# Divide code into parts

Tags: compiler-errors, compiler-construction, code-generation, compiler-optimization, cpu-architecture

Maybe it is simple question as I am not from compiler community. 
I have a function `f()`. I want to divide this function into `n` separate functions (say `f-1(),f-2()...f-n()`) with the objective that separated functions are less dependent. As a result:
calling `f()`  should be equal to calling `f-1();f-2();..f-n()`; with same data set. It is obvious that when doing this, you have to pass the snapshot of required variables from f-a() to f-b(), where a and b are separated functions called one after another. 
Is there known technique to pipeline the functions into separate ones so that they have very little dependencies between them. By that, I mean, little data to carry from `f-a()` to `f-b()`.

You can assume that I have an access to the AST of `f()`.

Comment: Well, that does not seem to be a simple question. In C compilers the procedure splitting typically can be made for part-inlining, for parallelizing or to split large procedures. May be you specify what for do you want to do it?

Comment: @alexanius thank you for your comment. I want to make pipelining with the specified function, like splitting it into smaller parts and executing the parts sequentially.

Comment: I don't know if there are such algorythms but this idea seems to be bad for performance. Usually we want to inline procedures for creating different optimization contexts. And if you divide procedure in such way (if it is possible to do without much dependencies) you will get few slow unoptimized procedures. May be some tricky parallelism will help you but now I can't imagine how to do this. But I did no work with parallelizing by myself so may be someone else will help you.